# How to change USB pendrive with 16.04 to boot using integrated graphics

Tags: intel-graphics, bootloader

Can anyone help?

My discrete graphics card (a Radeon HD 6970M) in my laptop has failed. There is no way to disable it in the BIOS and I can't remove the MXM from the motherboard. I'm able to disable it in Safe Mode for Windows but, as luck would have it, my windows installation has become corrupt too...

I have a USB pendrive installation of Ubuntu 16.04 that I use but, when it boots it tries to activate the AMD card immediately after the initial load before the menu appears. I just get a blank screen.

Is there a way I can modify the contents of the USB pendrive to force it to load using integrated graphics and ignore the defective Radeon?

I've seen a few threads advising using radeon.runpm=0 or radeon.modeset=0 options for grub but given I can't boot linux to run update-grub. The other way was using vgaswitcheroo but I can't see how to do that on the pendrive image.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can add those boot options directly in the live session (but it won't stay) according to the tips in the following link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/854527/how-to-unmount-a-live-dvd-usb/854538#854538 It is about 'toram' but you can add your boot options 'radeon.runpm=0' and 'radeon.modeset=0' in the same way.

Comment: Well I am thinking that might get the installer working and then you use boot repair with the correct options or install grub manually yourself so these two comments together might be the andswer

Comment: @sudodus That got me up and running. Many thanks.