# Lubuntu live CD is not working

Tags: boot, drivers, lubuntu, screen, live-cd

I get black screen when booting Lubuntu 16.04 live CD.  After some studying I found the reason is missing display driver.There is available a Ubuntu package for the driver.Is there a way to modify Lubuntu live CD so that it uses this driver when booting and also installs the package automatically when installation is selected from live CD menu? I prefer to use USB drive for live CD.

Comment: The open source display drivers are built-in in the live CD, so you don't need to install anything on the live CD. Your black screen when booting the live CD must be caused by something else.

Comment: Is it a CD? The current Lubuntu desktop iso files are too big for a CD. In order for it to work correctly, you need a DVD or a USB pendrive (or a memory card plus a USB adapter). - If it is a DVD, you can enter a boot option, for example try with **nomodeset** according to the description at https://askubuntu.com/questions/854527/how-to-unmount-a-live-dvd-usb Replace toram with nomodeset (or some other boot option).

Comment: I booted livecd on usb, using init 3 and took a look at existing drivers.  I think openchrome driver is missing, it tries with vesa driver but it fails resulting black screen.  I did copy missing kernel module to the stick using persistence and got picture on the screen so openchrome module is working fine when added, but there are some other complications (installation fails).  So I'm looking a robust way to add missing drivers for livecd booting, so that they are also installed by  livecd.