# USB to HDD Ubuntu installation

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 on a usb drive and I have no hard drive. Can I install ubuntu on the usb and then move the system off of my usb into a hard drive when I get one?

Comment: Yes, you can. Ubuntu is very flexible.

Comment: I will come back with a complete How To till tomorrow, i hope! But keep in mind that you will one more usb drive for what are what are u going to do.

Comment: It is possible in a two step procedure - also possible to install into the same drive (but more convenient if you have two USB pendrives). https://askubuntu.com/questions/855039/can-ubuntu-be-installed-to-the-pendrive-it-was-booted-from , https://askubuntu.com/questions/854527/how-to-unmount-a-live-dvd-usb/854538#854538 . Finally clone the system for example with Clonezilla.