# Install Error displaying "nouveau" and numbers

Tags: 16.04, boot, system-installation, nouveau

Please can someone just tell me what this error message means?

[image: screenshot]

I am trying to install Ubuntu on an HP Touch Smart 300. It doesn't have any other OS on it. Tried installing both 32 and 64 bit versions of Ubuntu 16.04.

I get to the `Try Ubuntu without installing` page and after it tries to boot it's just a white screen and these errors. I've tried all the help options and all result in a screen similar to this.

Comment: Try with the boot option `nomodeset` according to this link, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is nomodeset still required?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747314/is-nomodeset-still-required)

Comment: None of that is working. Also can't access grub menu to add nomodeset line.

Comment: Try the newest version of Ubuntu (in order to get the newest graphics drivers), Ubuntu 17.10.1, https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop (scroll down to find it).

Comment: I wasn't too sure about the latest release. But! I have now got it working. Those tutorials didn't specify where to type in 'nomodeset' since their load screens where a lot different to mine. Thank you, fellas!

Answer (score 1):

The word **nouveau** in the picture of the screen makes me think it is an issue with the graphics driver. Nouveau is the name of the free linux driver for nvidia graphics.

### Boot option **`nomodeset`**

Try with the boot option **`nomodeset`** to make Ubuntu work with nvidia graphics.

See these links and links from them for more details how to add a boot option,

[A post at the Ubuntu Forums: 'Boot options'](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808)

[My reply to a question at AskUbuntu: 'RAM drive'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854527/how-to-unmount-a-live-dvd-usb/854538?s=1|94.9641#854538) -- replace `toram` with `nomodeset`

Depending on the graphics card/chip model,

- maybe it will work well enough,
- maybe it will work, but you need [to install] a proprietary driver for the graphics to work really well. In this case you can start by searching the internet with the search string (without quotes) *'ubuntu 16.04 nvidia proprietary driver'*, and if it does not help you solve the problem, you can ask a separate question about it.